# Is that normal of QPainter to paint bad quality images?

Tags: python, qt, image-processing, qml

I want to show a stream of preprocessed Images. But their quality is bad .Here is the quality of QPainter in QQuickPaintedItem [painted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p6yH.png). Here is Output of Original image
in default Image view [Original Quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lzxj.png).
Here is the Paint Function I searched a lot and played with render hints. also in scaled function but no significant change

```
class LiveCamera(QQuickPaintedItem):

imageChanged=Signal(QImage)
def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()
    self.setRenderTarget(QQuickPaintedItem.FramebufferObject)

    self.m_image = QImage("C://Users//Hassan//Documents//python-gui-projects//PortMafiaSecurity//images//loading.jpg")


def paint(self,painter: QPainter):
    if self.m_image.isNull(): return
    img = self.m_image.scaled(self.size().toSize(),Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio )
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing,True);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform,True);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.LosslessImageRendering,True);
    x=QPixmap.fromImage(img)
    print(painter.testRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform))
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(),x)
```

So ,is that normal ? is there no way to draw higher quality ?

Comment: Are you using High DPI display? Maybe you should fiddle with device pixel ratio... It seems to me like your image was resized to too small size and and then upsized for High DPI display. What Qt version and what OS are you using?

Comment: I use qt creator 7.0.0 ,library pyside 6, os windows 10,i tried play with device pixel ratio it is just resize image smaller or bigger depend on value but still same quality.I tried to change scaling of windows no change ,also turned on fix scaling of app (windows option) no change so i think the problem is not in scaling. Thanks a lot, sorry for my bad english

Comment: What value of device pixel ratio you have when you print out `QGuiApplication::devicePixelRatio()`?

Comment: You should also use another paramater in `img = self.m_image.scaled(self.size().toSize(),Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation )`. Maybe it will help. However converting `QImage` to `QPixmap` is not neccessary and is suboptimal waste of processing power. Instead you should directly draw `QImage` with https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage

Comment: it returns 1.25 , I set aspect ratio to 1.25 just make image smaller with same quality .I tried Qimage only also same quality.  i will try to test program on another pc

Comment: To rule out that device pixel ratio plays a role, try also using `QGuiApplication::setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(Qt::HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy::RoundPreferFloor);`. This will round DPR down to 1.0 when drawing.

Comment: Try fiddling also with this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html#RenderTarget-enum ... rendering to QImage may offer better quality but worse performance.